# How to get all data from Pandas Dataframe when the data frame is showing these symbols ".." "..."?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to have my Pandas DataFrame output all the records in it, but the dataframe is cutting out rows with these symbols ".." and "..."

**Could any please show me how to get all the data in the dataframe?**

This what the output looks like now:

```
   'Column1' 'Column2'  
20   aaaaa     aaaa
21   aaaaa     aaaa
..  ...        ...
600 aaaaa     aaaa
```

This what I want it to look like sequential:

```
'Column1' 'Column2'  
20   aaaaa     aaaa
21   aaaaa     aaaa
22   aaaaa     aaaa
```

Code:

```
    import ET_Client
    import pandas as pd



    try:
        debug = False
        stubObj = ET_Client.ET_Client(False, debug)

        ## Modify the date below to reduce the number of results returned from the request
        ## Setting this too far in the past could result in a very large response size
        retrieveDate = '2016-07-11T13:00:00.000'

        #ET call for clicks
        print '>>>ClickEvents'
        getClickEvent = ET_Client.ET_ClickEvent()
        getClickEvent.auth_stub = stubObj   
        getResponse = getClickEvent.get()
        ResponseResults = getResponse.results
        #print ResponseResults


        Client = []
        partner_keys = []
        created_dates = []
        modified_date = []
        ID = []
        ObjectID = []
        SendID = []
        SubscriberKey = []
        EventDate = []
        EventType = []
        TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID = []
        BatchID = []
        URLID = []
        URL = []




        for ClickEvent in ResponseResults:
            Client.append(str(ClickEvent['Client']['ID']))
            partner_keys.append(ClickEvent['PartnerKey'])
            created_dates.append(ClickEvent['CreatedDate'])
            modified_date.append(ClickEvent['ModifiedDate'])
            ID.append(ClickEvent['ID'])
            ObjectID.append(ClickEvent['ObjectID'])
            SendID.append(ClickEvent['SendID'])
            SubscriberKey.append(ClickEvent['SubscriberKey'])
            EventDate.append(ClickEvent['EventDate'])
            EventType.append(ClickEvent['EventType'])
            TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID.append(ClickEvent['TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID'])
            BatchID.append(ClickEvent['BatchID'])
            URLID.append(ClickEvent['URLID'])
            URL.append(ClickEvent['URL'])


        df = pd.DataFrame({'ClientID': Client, 'PartnerKey': partner_keys,
                       'CreatedDate' : created_dates, 'ModifiedDate': modified_date, 
                       'ID':ID, 'ObjectID': ObjectID,'SendID':SendID,'SubscriberKey':SubscriberKey,
                       'EventDate':EventDate,'EventType':EventType,'TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID':TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID,
                       'BatchID':BatchID,'URLID':URLID,'URL':URL})

        print df  
except Exception as e:
    print 'Caught exception: ' + e.message
    print e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [display](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#frequently-used-options) problem. One possible solution is use:

```
#temporaly display 999 rows
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', 999):
    print df
```